# Python on visual studio generate error

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I installed Python 3.5.2 and Python for visual studio.

I created a very simple project to test Python and when I try to run it, I am getting an error:

```
The environment Pyhthon 3.5 appears to be incorrectly configured or missing.
You may need to install Python 3.5 or re create a virtual environment.
```

I check the python virtual environment on visual studio and it seems correct and also exists.

What can I do to fix this problem?

I am using Python 3.5.2, Visual studio 2013 on windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Python 3.5?

Comment: @Aidenhjj: No, As the Python works properly, I am not sure it is the problem, but I am going to do this as a test.

Comment: @Aidenhjj: After re installing Python, it create a new environment and when I select the new environment, it is working now.

Comment: Great. If in doubt, turn it off and on again. haha